# InvalidAuthenticityToken with destroy in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

On RSpec, the destroy action fails in `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`.

I don't think this is a problem as `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:index, :show]` in my Controller is enough to fix the problem, but it still bothers me that this has to happen and it seems like it could be a bad security practice.

-

Here's the would-be-failing RSpec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Products" do
    subject { page }
    ...
    describe "Destroy" do
        before {
            FactoryGirl.create(:product)
            visit products_path
        }
        it "should have a destroy link" do
            expect { should have_link('Destroy') }
        end
        it "link should destroy" do
            expect do
                click_link('Destroy', match: :first)
            end.to change(Product, :count).by(-1)
        end
    end
end
```

-

And here's the controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:destroy] #destroy wasn't working without this

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    ...
  end

  def update
    ...
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Product was successfully destroyed."
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
end
```

-

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, skipping your authenticity token check is a bad idea. At the very least, ensure you are only doing that for your test environment:

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:destroy] if Rails.env.test?`

The issue with invalid tokens when you run tests may be the result of running your tests in your development environment.

Ensure your `test_helper.rb` file is correctly setting the environment:

`Rails.env = 'test'`

This works better than the `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'` style approach.

Best of luck! Did you happen to find any other resolution?